# jQuery replaceWith Inside Loop malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

So here's what i was trying to do. if I click on update button, the text on the left side will be an INPUT box like below:
[Click the update button and the text on the left will be an input box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlw8a.png)

BUT what's really happening is all the text on the left side is getting replaced with INPUT box, image here:
[all text left side is affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmgAx.png)

how do I use a unique id or something? sorry I'm new to this jQuery stuff. And can you please explain how I can edit the table affected on MySQL?

code here:

```
<table class="table no-margin">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th width="250px">Category</th>
                <th width="20px"> </th>
                <th width="20px"> </th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php 
                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  $tcategory = $rows['vCategory'];
                  $cid = $rows['id'];
              ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo '<div class="editable">'. $tcategory .' </div>'; ?>

                </td>
                <td><button id="edit" class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-success"> Update</button> </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-block btn-xs btn-danger">  Delete</button> </td>

                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <script>
                  $("#edit").click(function() {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    if($this.attr('editing') != '1') {
                      $this.text('Save').attr('editing', 1);
                      $(document).find('.editable').each(function() {
                        var input = $('<input class="editing" />').val($(this).text());
                        $(this).replaceWith(input);
                      });
                    }else {
                      $this.text('Update').removeAttr('editing');
                      $(document).find('input.editing').each(function() {
                        var div = $('<div class="editable" />').text($(this).val());
                        $(this).replaceWith(div);
                      });
                    }
                  });
                </script>
                </tr>
                <form>
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="addCategory" placeholder="Enter New Category"></td>
                  <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-success" value="Add"></td>
                </tr>
                </form>   

              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: you cannot give same edit id to all elements in the loop

Comment: okay, but it's inside my loop I'm just getting the category column from my database that's why it's inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put same class in all edit button. Remove the edit id. Remember IDs are unique.Try something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/v2bxdttz/

use

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.editable').each(function() {
```

instead of

```
 $(document).find('.editable').each(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question, how do you update the edited text to it's column on the database? Sorry for being such a noob at jQuery

Comment: use ajax to fetch the value from the textbox and update database